# Linkedin oAuth for win Phone 8.1

Tags: webview, oauth-2.0, windows-phone-8.1, linkedin-api

i am developing a Win Phone 8.1 Application with LinkedIn oAuth 2.0 Login 
but when i tried to get Authorization Code for my app 
i am not getting Authorisation Code because in response i get html code 
 
and i have assigned it to my WebView Control by NavigateToString(HTMLstring)
In an artical i have seen that we have to add a page with WebView control
and navigate to oAuth provider in this control 
is this approach right or i have to do it by any other way?
please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With WP8.1 to connect to OAuth2.0 it's better to use the `WebAuthenticationBroker`

You can find the MSDN documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227025

Here the general example: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122#content

And here one with LinkedIn: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/LinkedIn-OAuth-20-Example-408dd568